# Trouble getting require.js to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, requirejs

I'm trying to use [require js](http://requirejs.org/) with CakePHP 2.3.8 but I'm not having any luck getting it working. I have the following in my default.ctp file

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="http://localhost/Test/js/require.js"></script>
```

When I include this, I get the following error `Uncaught Error: Script error for: main`

I have the following structure

```
App/
   webroot/
         js/
            require.js
            main.js
            helper/
                   date.js
```

I tried pointing "data-main" to the folder that require.js is in, and the error goes away, however, the date.js script is not loading

```
<script data-main="http://localhost/Test/js/" src="http://localhost/Test/js/require.js"></script>
```

I want to include date.js, so in main.js I have the following

```
require(["date"], function() {

});
```

I'm using chrome, and when I check the scripts and network tab, date.js does not show up.

Comment: An opening or closing tag? I'm not sure I know what you're talking about. I may have missed that in the installation guide.

Comment: Would the placement make a difference? Regardless, I tried it and it does not work.

Comment: No that should not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `data-main='http://localhost/Test/js/'` to `data-main='http://localhost/Test/js/main'`. To get `date.js` to work, you must do something like:

```
require(['helper/date'], function() {

});
```

Comment: Throws an error saying "Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module:" along with the rest of the entire require.js file. I did try .../js/main/ but it failed to load. I checked the response and it said "Error: Create the class JsController below in file: app/Controller/JsController.php"

Comment: The way I wrote it is correct for `main.js`. Now see my edit.

Comment: That's it! Thank you!. What exactly does data-main do? I understand what the file does, but within the script tag? Why wouldn't it point to main.js and not main (without the extension)?

Comment: Shows `require.js` where to run your `require()` functions from.